# JQuery: element - get final css value(s) during animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Consider the following scenario:

```
element.css({display:'none'});
element.slideDown(1000);
// ...
// here I want to get the final height
```

What is the right method to get the **final** value of an animation **before** it's finished? If I access the css properties directly I get the current values. I simplified the case above. The actual code is not bound in the same function so I can't just create a variable to hold that value for me to refer to later.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I think I couldn't express well what I'm trying to do.
My question, revised:

```
element.css({display:'none'});
element.slideDown(1000);

btn.click(function() {
    var finalHeight = element..?
    var str = 'height of the element will be ' + finalHeight;
    str += ' when the animation is complete';
    alert(str);
}
```

Consider clicking this button before the animation is completed.

Comment: Why are you calling it the final height if you just want the height during the animation? The final height would be the height when the animation is complete.

Comment: Exactly. And that's what I'm trying to get.

Comment: The final height would be the height when the animation is done i.e. at 1000ms. It appears that you want the height at specific intervals. You might try using setInterval to poll for the height but that just seems messy.

Comment: No intervals, only when user clicks on a button. I just wanted to prevent possible suggestions that relies on basic calculations such as *2 /2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you need the final height? If you need the height once the animation is complete, you can easily attach a callback function as second argument to `.slideDown` that reads the css properties (or `$(this).height()`) once the animation is complete.

If you want to predict the final height of the animation while it is still running, things are not so simple because AFAIK you can only access the computed height of elements that are already rendered by the browser, you cannot read the height of elements in future renderings. But if you hide the element before sliding it in, maybe you could attach the computed height (`.height()`) to the DOM-Element using `.data()` before you're hiding it and then just read this value to get the final height.

Edit:

Actually, the things could be pretty simple: Just read the height of the element using `css('height')` **before** starting the animation (but after hiding it) and store the value using `data`: Look here for an example: [**http://jsfiddle.net/QNDcv/**](http://jsfiddle.net/QNDcv/)

Comment: Well I won't have access to that, either. But I know I can access this data somehow by `element.etc[.etc[...]]`. I made it output the all (147) properties and I saw there are timers working there during the animation, all of which are accessed from within the `stop` function. So I think I should be able to access them, too.

Comment: What kind of element is it that you are slding down?

Comment: Look at the fiddle of my edited answer. I hope it does match your case.

Comment: For now I ended up doing the exact same thing. For each element I'm making it `display:block`, attach it its height using `.data('finalHeight',etc)`, hiding it and making it delete this data once it finishes animating. But I still think there must be some other way. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: You don't have to display the element to get its height. You just have to get the height before you start the animation, the element does not have to be visible. BTW, thats basically how jQuery determines the final height internally to compute the animation steps.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to use [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)'s callback function:

```
element.slideDown(1000, function() {
    var h = $(this).height();
    // Now do things with 'h'.
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/P47Cj/1/

Comment: Doesn't that trigger at the end of animation?

Comment: @inhan: Yes it does, that's when you know how tall it is going to be. Trying to force synchronous behavior onto an asynchronous system is a recipe for bugs and frustration. The standard pattern with jQuery and JavaScript is to use callbacks all over the place.

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery's height function.

element.height();

Comment: That gives the current value. I'm trying to get the final one.

Comment: I meant after the animation had finished. You will need to use a callback function, not just put it immediately after the slideDown call

Comment: I could get the value using straight-forward `css('height')` if I waited until the end. My question is how can I get that **final** value **before** the animation has finished. Thanks, though.